# How to fix "Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777" error after running "rails s"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried changing the permissions but it's still not working. I created a new Rails app to test it and got the  same error when I tried to start the Rails server.
And I get the same error when I run `rails -v` in the application folder.

How do I fix this?

`rails s` output:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:39: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777
    /usr/bin/ruby2.5: warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems
    Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.0
    Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0       
    Ignoring nio4r-2.5.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.5.2
    Ignoring nokogiri-1.10.7 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.10.7
    Ignoring websocket-driver-0.7.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.7.1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
            4: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
            3: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
            2: from /mnt/c/Users/max/Desktop/Dev/app_project/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
            1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'


gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.5', '>= 2.5.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.4.1'

gem 'devise', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'toastr-rails'

gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.9'

gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 5.0'
```

`lsb_release -a` output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

`rvm list` output:

```
=* ruby-2.6.5 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

`gem -v` output:

```
3.1.2
```

`ruby -v` output:

```
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: "When i run “rails s”, i get “Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777” error" - This is *not* an error, it is a *warning*. It clearly says so: "warning: Insecure world writable dir ...". "I've tried changing permissions but still not working." is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Note again that the message you quoted is a *warning*, it is *not* an error. It does not cause your code to fail, it is simply warning you that your directory permissions are insecure.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue on Windows 10 WSL, Ubuntu 18.04, and I solved it by:

- Opening or initializing `wsl.conf` file under the `/etc` folder like this: `sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf`
- Adding these two lines in the document:

```
[automount]
options="metadata,umask=0033"
```

- Saving the document by: pressing `CTRL`+`X` shortcut, then pressing `Y`, then `Enter` key to confirm the changes
- Restarting my computer (**Very important for changes to take effect**)

References:

- [Microsoft Dev Blog: Automatically Configuring WSL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/)
- [Github - Microsoft/WSL: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777 #1426](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1426)

Comment: Instead of restarting the computer, you could run `wsl --shutdown` from PowerShell or CMD, and then opening the Ubuntu terminal again.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using WSL?

Since C drive (`/mnt/c`) is a Windows partition it doesn't share the file/dir permission system from Ubuntu(Linux).

"[warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777 #1426](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1426)" from WSL can be useful.

Comment: Yes, I'm using WSL. But i don't get it, this works perfectly on my workstation. So why this error on my laptop?

Comment: did you clone the repo from wsl or from windows? that makes a difference sometimes. Other way to do it is clone the repo from WSL to the Ubuntu ~/ dir and access the project with Vscode remote WSL (code . from WSL installs it), but that if I'm been lazy.

Comment: I cloned the repo inside vscode using the command palette and then created a branch. Then i guess i'll have to clone again but this time to the Ubuntu dir as you suggest?

Comment: if you use git from windows, theres a chance that you change the line endings of the files to clrf('\r\n' instead of '\n' thats used in unix like systems). when using that files from wsl that can be troublesome ( in fact, you have a warning about that when says  '/usr/bin/ruby2.5: warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems') thats why in wsl I usually clone from wsl itself.

Comment: Exactly, was about to ask a question on this error i'm facing at the moment '/usr/bin/ruby2.5: warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems').

Comment: @Richard: "Exactly, was about to ask a question on this error i'm facing at the moment" - This is not an error, it is a warning. It clearly says so: "warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems".

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this on macOS while I was doing things with `Cocoapods`. `sudo chmod 755 /your/directory` helped me get rid of this issue. Hope it can work for you.